# Bootstrap theme recognition from website

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, themes, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a website which was built with twitter bootstrap. How do I find out what is the name of the bootstrap theme? Is there a place in the code where I can find the theme name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no specific standards on the naming or development of Bootstrap themes. Look in the HEAD section of the HTML and you can find the CSS files that the theme is using.

Comment: Is new chrome or FF debug tool capable of detecting the theme name yet? Or any other simple way?